# Event Binding on Dynamically Created Line Items with Parameter

Tags: jquery

I am creating a dynamic list of connected users using jQuery.  I am having an issue binding to the click event and passing a parameter to it.

The code that is creating the dynamic line items is as follows:

```
setTimeout(function () {
  $(".kt-subheader__toolbar").html('<span class="noti" id="editDash"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="24px" height="24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" version="1.1" class="kt-svg-icon"><g stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd"><path d="M17,12 L18.5,12 C19.3284271,12 20,12.6715729 20,13.5 C20,14.3284271 19.3284271,15 18.5,15 L5.5,15 C4.67157288,15 4,14.3284271 4,13.5 C4,12.6715729 4.67157288,12 5.5,12 L7,12 L7.5582739,6.97553494 C7.80974924,4.71225688 9.72279394,3 12,3 C14.2772061,3 16.1902508,4.71225688 16.4417261,6.97553494 L17,12 Z" fill="#000000" /><rect fill="#000000" opacity="0.3" x="10" y="16" width="4" height="4" rx="2" /></g></svg><span class="count">&nbsp;</span></span><div class="noti-content"><div class="noti-top-arrow"></div> <ul id="notiContent"></ul></div>');
  $("#editDash").on("click", function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('.noti-content').show();
    var count = 0;
    count = parseInt($('span.count').html()) || 0;
    //only load notification if not already loaded
    if (count > 0) {

      getUserNotifications();

    }
    $('span.count', this).html('&nbsp;');
  })
}, 2000);

function getUserNotifications() {

  $('#notiContent').empty();
  $.each(connectedUsers, function (index, value) {

    $('#notiContent').append($('<li onclick="startUserChat(' + value.ConnectionId + ')">New contact : ' + value.UserName + ' (' + value.ConnectionId + ')</li>'));

  })
}

function startUserChat(connectionId) {
  alert("Start chat with user: " + connectionId);
}
```

I not only need to call the "`startUserChat(connectionId)`" function when a line item is clicked but I also need to pass the connectionId from that line item to the function.  Currently, I am unable to get the onclick to fire at all, I realize that it is because the line items are created dynamically, and I have looked at a few solutions that say I need to bind to a parent element, but then how do I pass the parameter?

Comment: Event delegation is just changing `$("#editDash").on("click", function (e) {` to `$(document).on("click", "#editDash", function (e) {` - there's no "parameters" in your direct on click, so there's none on the event delegation.   I'm not 100% sure this is your problem but worth changing that line in the first instance

Comment: if **connectionId** is a string you need to double quote:  $('#notiContent').append($('<li onclick="startUserChat(\'' + value.ConnectionId + '\')">......

Comment: @freedomn-m, I'm not really understanding what you are saying.  startUserChat(connectionId) is what I am having a problem calling and getting the connectionId parameter.

Comment: I'm sure you've read it, but review [mcve] - looks like I've picked up on the *event binding* (as in the title/question) but your issue (from @gaetanoM 's comment) is to do with `onclick=`.   Please only included the *minimal* code required.

Comment: Is your `startUserChat` defined inside doc.ready?  Do you get any console errors?  Using onclick= with dynamically generated html is not an issue in itself.

Comment: Your code works just fine [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/21v6cd8h/1/) .. so please `console.log(value.ConnectionId);` before append and check if its a correct value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is supposed to be working... The only reason I see to make it non-working is `value.ConnectionId` maybe is a string.

So I suggest you to use [templating literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), so the quote issues would be easier to manage than a string concatenation.

Try this:

```
$('#notiContent').append($(`<li onclick="startUserChat('${value.ConnectionId}')">New contact : ${value.UserName} (${value.ConnectionId})</li>`));
```

Notice there are some quotes around the passed argument `${value.ConnectionId}`.