# jQuery animate executes the same time each time, even though the position has changed - any ideas?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I currently have a div that moves left on touchstart - this works well but if the user presses and releases multiple times the animation resets to 3 seconds every time - meaning it gets gradually slower. Any ideas or help would be appreciated.

```
$(".buttonLeft").on('touchstart', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  var myDiv = $(".cart01");
  myDiv.clearQueue();
  myDiv.stop();

  $(".cart01").stop().animate({"left": "340px"}, 3000, easing, function() {
    console.log("Cart01 left complete");
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps combine `myDiv.is(':animated')` with your existing code.

```
var myDiv = $(".cart01");
if (!myDiv.is(':animated')) {
  myDiv.animate({
    "left": "234px"
  }, 3000, "linear", function() {
    console.log("Cart01 left complete");
  });
}
```

Note for the demo I had changed `touchstart` to `click`

**Demo**

```js
$(".buttonLeft").on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var myDiv = $(".cart01");
  if (!myDiv.is(':animated')) {
    myDiv.animate({
      "left": "234px"
    }, 3000, "linear", function() {
      console.log("Cart01 left complete");
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.t {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
}

.cart01 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="buttonLeft">buttonLeft</button>


<div class="t">
  <div class="cart01">cart01</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry it still queues the animation - if you click it multiple times it gets gradually slower to reach its target.

Answer (score 0):

- To use `touch` one time only .. you can use `.one` instead of `.on`

```js
$(".buttonLeft").one('click', function(e) { 
  e.preventDefault();
  var $this = $(this);
  var Cart = $(".cart01");
  Cart.animate({
    "left": "100px"
  }, 3000, "linear", function() {
    console.log("Animation completed ");
  });
});
```

```css
.cart01 {
  position: fixed;
  padding : 10px;
  top : 50px;
  left : 0;
  background : red;
  color : #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
 <div class="cart01">cart01</div>

<button class="buttonLeft">buttonLeft</button>
```

- To be sure that the animation is finished before the next `click/touch`- Use `add/removeClass` with `:not` selector , You will need [event-binding-on-dynamically-created-line-items-with-parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65998319/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-line-items-with-parameter#) because the class in this case will added dynamically

```js
var num = 0;
$(document).on('click', ".buttonLeft:not(.animating)", function(e) { // use :not selector to prevent the click from the `animating` class
  e.preventDefault();
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.addClass('animating'); // add the animating class
  var Cart = $(".cart01");
  Cart.animate({
    "left": num == 0 ? "100px" : "0px"
  }, 3000, "linear", function() {
    console.log("Animation completed ");
    num = num == 0 ? 1 : 0;
    $this.removeClass('animating'); // remove the animating class
  });
});
```

```css
.cart01 {
  position: fixed;
  padding : 10px;
  top : 50px;
  left : 0;
  background : red;
  color : #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
 <div class="cart01">cart01</div>

<button class="buttonLeft">buttonLeft</button>
```